# failed to acquire lease: subnet "10.244.0.0/16" specified in the flannel net config doesn't contain "192.168.0.0/24"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to configure Kubernetes with web dashboard. I use these steps:

```shell
swapoff -a
```

Remove following line from `/etc/fstab`

```shell
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

then run these shell commands:

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker.io
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker 
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" >> ~/kubernetes.list
sudo mv ~/kubernetes.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubeadm kubelet kubectl kubernetes-cni
    
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
    
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

I applied this configuration:

```yaml
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: flannel-fix
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: flannel
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: flannel
    namespace: kube-flannel
```

```shell
kubectl create -f <file>
```

But I get:

```shell
Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: subnet "10.244.0.0/16" specified in the flannel net config doesn't contain "192.168.0.0/24" PodCIDR of the "ubuntukubernetis1" node
```

Do you know what should be the correct configuration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot start Kubernetis Dashboard](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16335/cannot-start-kubernetis-dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by reading the documentation:

> Take care that your Pod network must not overlap with any of the host networks: you are likely to see problems if there is any overlap.

Flannel uses 10.244.0.0/16 and can't run on the same as your host... it creates new interfaces when implemented. So when you run this init command it should always be using 10.244.0.0/16.

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Once I did this, things started working as expected.